# Canvas Images and S3 (CORS policy)

Tags: canvas, amazon-s3, coffeescript, cors

Currently i working on canvas gallery and I've been stucked on CORS problems. So i really don't know from which moment I should start and I'll just try to describe steps I've done and describe my trouble.

**Introduction:**

I use CoffeeScript, jQuery and all my images stored on Amazon S3.

**The Problem**

So, first CORS config of my bucket is pretty like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://level.travel</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Origin</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*.level.travel</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Origin</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

and similar rules for development environment (different domains, of course).

On gallery initialization I just collect URLs for images and then some information about them. This functionality is provided by this part of code:

```
images_array.each (i, image)=>
    console.log "Loading image #{i}"
    canvas_image                = new Image
    canvas                      = document.createElement('canvas')
    canvas_context              = canvas.getContext("2d")
    canvas_image.crossOrigin    = 'anonymous'
    image_index                 = i

    canvas_image.onload         = =>
        canvas.width        = canvas_image.naturalWidth
        canvas.height       = canvas_image.naturalHeight
        canvas_context.drawImage(canvas_image, 0, 0)
        localStorage.setItem(@storage_ns(i), canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'))
        @full_images[i]     = $(image).data("fullImage")
        @hidden_area.append(canvas)
        @progress_event(canvas, image_index)

    canvas_image.onerror        = => @error_event(image_index)

    if canvas_image.complete || canvas_image.complete is undefined
        canvas_image.src    = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
        canvas_image.src    = $(image).data("thumbImage")
```

This is [MDN solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image) extended for my needs.

Method `@progress_event` puts each image in array (like in-memory cache) with some additional information provided. This array looks like this:

```
[
    {
        image   : canvas    // the canvas element which will be drawed on main Canvas
        small   : { ... }   // information about small images (eg. size, position)
        large   : { ... }   // similar to small
    }
]
```

Then the most interesting part and (i suppose) my problem:

Gallery consists of two tapes (large and small images on the top of each other). To draw both tapes I need to run `@render_gallery_tape` two times. Those functions executes in infinite loop (`setTimeout`, 45 FPS) and works in `requestAnimationFrame`.

This is how i call `@render_gallery_tape`:

```
@render_gallery_tape('large')
@render_gallery_tape('small')
```

`@render_gallery_tape` is asynchronous and both functions works simultaneously.

In `@render_gallery_tape` I have this:

```
// pane is an item of array described above
// @cache_context is a context of off-screen Canvas
@cache_context.drawImage(pane.image,
                         Math.ceil(current_offset),
                         Math.ceil(margin_top),
                         Math.ceil(size.width),
                         Math.ceil(size.height))
```

So sometimes when my gallery tries to render small (bottom) tape I getting security error (CORS policy). Browser thinks that I have wrong origin.

I understand that I can proxy those images (using nginx for example) but we use EC2 and I don't want to increase traffic on application server. So I forced to use S3.

Thanks in advance.

**P.S.** I can provide any additional information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

might not be your issue, but make sure that in your `crossorigin="use-credentials"` to your `<video>` tag.

"The  element keeps track of where the data inside of it comes from, and if it knows that you got something from another website (for example, if the  element you painted into the canvas is pointing to a cross-origin file), it’ll “taint” the canvas."

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it. But we already solved this problem by using nginx-proxy for Amazon S3 traffic (all S3 traffic for those images is now goes through our EC2 servers).

Comment: better you did, as not many browsers honor the crossorigin attribute

Comment: We support only modern browsers e.g. IE9+, Chrome, Opera, Safari etc. So browsers support is not the first priority. But yes, it was more simpler than trying to make CORS working.